# Add row to table on entering a value in last table cell

Tags: jquery, dynamic, html-table, append, row

I want to add a new row to my table when I enter data into the last table cell.

I have seen this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yUfhL/) on how to do so with a link. I want to alter this so that the additional row is added with onChange in the last td.

So, using jquery 1.7, the code is:

```
<table class="authors-list">
  <tr><td>author's first name</td><td>author's last name</td></tr>
  <tr><td><input type="text" name="first_name" /></td><td><input type="text" name="last_name" /></td></tr>
</table>
<a href="#" title="" class="add-author">Add Author</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
var counter = 1;
jQuery('a.add-author').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    counter++;
    var newRow = jQuery('<tr><td><input type="text" name="first_name' +
        counter + '"/></td><td><input type="text" name="last_name' +
        counter + '"/></td></tr>');
    jQuery('table.authors-list').append(newRow);
});
</script>
```

I want to change this to dynamically add the row on changing / entering data into the last TD.

Something like,

```
<table class="authors-list">
  <tr><td>author's first name</td><td>author's last name</td></tr>
  <tr><td><input type="text" name="first_name" /></td><td><input type="text" name="last_name" onclick="add-author"/></td></tr>
</table>


<script type="text/javascript">
var counter = 1;
jQuery('a.add-author').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    counter++;
    var newRow = jQuery('<tr><td><input type="text" name="first_name' +
        counter + '"/></td><td><input type="text" name="last_name' +
        counter + '"/></td></tr>');
    jQuery('table.authors-list').append(newRow);
});
</script>
```

So the onclick / onchange triggers the jQuery to add a new row, with a uniqu id as per the counter value.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `on` change event for the input so that it work for dynamically added row's input too.

try this

**updated**

```
var counter = 1;
jQuery("table.authors-list").on('change','input[name^="first_name"]',function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  counter++;
  var newRow = jQuery('<tr><td><input type="text" name="first_name' +
    counter + '"/></td><td><input type="text" name="last_name' +
    counter + '"/></td><td><a class="deleteRow"> x </a></td></tr>');
  jQuery('table.authors-list').append(newRow);
});

 jQuery("table.authors-list").on('click','.deleteRow',function(event){

   $(this).closest('tr').remove();
 });
```

i am taking the change event for `firstname` input here.. you can change it to any selector you want...

**NOTE: for input change event is triggerd only when that particular input is blured (when it loose its focus)**

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/bipen/yUfhL/206/)
[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bipen/yUfhL/212/)

Comment: Thanks @bipen. works great for what I need, thinking it through the first cell actually makes more sense. anyway, if I wanted to delete the current row is it easy to add this on? Thanks again.

Comment: yes.. you have to modify your code and add another elements..hang on

Comment: legendary. thanks Bipen. I will just need to run through this code to make sure I understand it correctly. it does work perfectly, just the styling is not applying. any advice appreciated but thanks for your input. Cheers,

Comment: yes you can style the `x` there.. or use image there.. any element you use, its just that it should have  the `class="deleteRow"` for the click to work.. anyways welcome.. glad it helped.. hapy coding.. cheers..:)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this will do it, although it would present a few other bugs that you will need to iron out depending on what you're ultimately trying to achieve.

By triggering on keyup rather than change you can edit the content without adding a further blank row.

http://jsfiddle.net/yUfhL/209/

```
var counter = 1;
jQuery("table.authors-list").on("keyup", "input[name*='last_name']", function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    if($(this).val().length == 1) {
    counter++;
    var newRow = jQuery('<tr><td><input type="text" name="first_name' +
        counter + '"/></td><td><input type="text" name="last_name' +
        counter + '"/></td></tr>');

        jQuery('table.authors-list').append(newRow);
    }
});
```